# How can I add a new method to FormattedString?

Tags: c#

In my C# code I use this kind of construct many times:

```
FormattedString s = new FormattedString();
s.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "On the ", ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("555555") });
s.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "settings", ForegroundColor = Color.Blue });
```

I would like to simplify this to something like:

```
FormattedString s = new FormattedString();
s.Spans.AddGray("On the ");
s.Spans.AddBlue("settings");
```

or even better

```
s.AddGray("On the ");
s.AddBlue("settings");
```

Is there a way that I can do this by somehow extending the capabilities of a FormattedString?

Comment: You want Extension Methods

Comment: Yes, read about extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a couple of [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method):

```
public static void AddGray(this FormattedString formattedString, string text)
    => formattedString.Add(text, Color.FromHex("555555"));

public static void AddBlue(this FormattedString formattedString, string text)
    => formattedString.Add(text, Color.Blue);
```

Common logic is moved to another extension method which allows specifying color:

```
public static void Add(this FormattedString formattedString, string text, Color color)
    => formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = text, ForegroundColor = color });
```

Then you can add colored spans:

```
s.AddGray("On the ");
s.AddBlue("settings");
s.Add("imprtant", Color.Red);
```

---

Note that I would make names of methods more descriptive - `AddGraySpan`, `AddBlueSpan`, `AddSpan`. I would also return original `FormattedString` instance from each extension method. That would allow you to use fluent API:

```
var s = new FormattedString().AddGraySpan("On the ").AddBlueSpan("settings");
```

Sample of implementation:

```
public static FormattedString AddSpan(this FormattedString formattedString,
   string text, Color color)
{
    formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = text, ForegroundColor = color });
    return formattedString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but how would this work in the first two code snippets as I need to add it to the Spans part of the FormattedString?

Comment: @Alan2 that is what happening in the third method

Comment: Thanks.  the third method looks good and I will try to use that.  But I am still wondering about the first two methods. Don't those need to include formattedString.Spans.Add ?

Comment: Your last update looks very good indeed.  If you don't mind could you give an example of the AddGraySpan or AddBlueSpan coding.

Comment: @Alan2 nope, they both pass appropriate color to the third method

Comment: Can you confirm that the last example return type should be FormattedString?  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 yes, sorry. Missed return type when copy-pasted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method).

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace CustomExtensions
{
    public static class FormattedStringExtension
    {
        public static void AddGray(this FormattedString formattedString, string x)
        {
            // TODO: Do something
        }

        public static void AddBlue(this FormattedString formattedString, string x)
        {
            // TODO: Do something
        }

        // etc... 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could fill in the // TODO it would be much appreciated :-)